# How can I delete all rows that do not include a specific value?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been struggling with this for a few hours and think it's probably time to ask for help.

I have hundreds of spreadsheets that I would like to manually open and then simplify using a macro. Each spreadsheet has a list of hospitals (approx 400) and I would like to limit each one to only showing data about 100 hospitals. The hospitals are identified by a three letter acronym in a column that varies in location (row/column) but is always titled "Code".

So, for example, I would like the macro to delete all rows that do not contain the values "Code", "ABC", "DEF", "GEH", etc.

I am not a regular Excel user and only need to use it to solve this one problem...!

I have tried the code attached but it has a couple of bugs:

- It deletes rows that contain "ABC" as well. This problem goes away if I define Range("B1:B100") but not if the range extends across multiple columns (e.g. "A1:E100"). Frustratingly the "Code" column varies across the spreadsheets.
- As I want to save 100 hospital codes, it feels as if there ought to be a better way than using the "Or" operator 100 times.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub Clean()
Dim c As Range
Dim MyRange As Range
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = Range("A1:E100")
For Each c In MyRange
  If c.Value = "Code" Then
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
  ElseIf c.Value = "ABC" Or c.Value = "DEF" Then
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
  Else
    c.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting rows, you will want to use backwards stepping index loop instead of a `For Each` loop or you will have many problems.

Comment: This is a perfect example of when to use the [Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/select-case-statement) statement

Comment: @tigeravatar Why?

Comment: @braX The best way to do it is to delete the rows in one go instead of 1 by 1. Have a look at my answer below. The fastest and safest solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clean()

    Dim rngRow      As Range
    Dim rngCell     As Range
    Dim MyRange     As Range
    Dim blnDel      As Boolean
    Dim lngCount    As Long

    Set MyRange = Range("A1:E8")

    For lngCount = MyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

        blnDel = False
        For Each rngCell In MyRange.Rows(lngCount).Cells

            If rngCell = "ABC" Then

                rngCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                blnDel = True

            ElseIf rngCell = "DEF" Then
                rngCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                blnDel = True
            End If
        Next rngCell

        If Not blnDel Then Rows(lngCount).Delete
    Next lngCount

End Sub
```

In general, you need to loop through the rows, and then through each cell in every row. In order for the program to remember whether something should be deleted or not on a given row, between the two loops there is a `blnDel`, which deletes the row, if no `DEF` or `ABC` was found.

The problematic part in rows deletion in VBA, is that you should be careful to delete always the correct one. Thus, you should make a reversed loop, starting from the last row.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Clean()
    Dim c As Range, MyRange As Range, DelRng As Range, Code As Range, CodeList As Range
    Dim CodeCol As Long, LastRow As Long

    ''Uncomment the below. I'd put all of your codes into one sheet and then test if the value is in that range
    'With CodeListSheet
    '    Set CodeList = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    'End With

    ' Update this to point at the relevant sheet
    ' If you're looking at multiple sheets you can loop through the sheets starting your loop here
    With Sheet1
        Set Code = .Cells.Find("Code")
        If Not Code Is Nothing Then
            CodeCol = Code.Column
            LastRow = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, CodeCol).End(xlUp).Row
            Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, CodeCol), .Cells(LastRow, CodeCol))

            For Each c In MyRange
                If c.Value2 = "Code" Then
                    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
                '' Also uncomment this one to replace your current one
                'ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CodeList, c.Value2) > 0 Then
                ElseIf UCase(c.Value2) = "ABC" Or c.Value2 = "DEF" Then
                    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Else
                    If DelRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set DelRng = c
                    Else
                        Set DelRng = Union(DelRng, c)
                    End If
                End If
            Next c

            If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            MsgBox "Couldn't find correct column"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `DelRng.EntireRow.Delete` does not work and spoils the whole solution. Take a look at my solution to see how to delete rows.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Used this method plenty of times, works fine

Comment: Just write the following in `A1 to A8`, run your method and see yourself : ABC|ABC|AAA|AAA|DEF|DEF|ABC|ABC.

Comment: Actually the problem is in the way you set `DelRng` in the second `Else`. Thus, the `DelRng` gets polluted.

Comment: What's the address of `DelRng` that you're getting? Mine returns `$A$3:$A$4`

Comment: Think the reason is because the range is defined as `A:E` columns so if anything is blank it deletes that row. The technique works fine, the range is what's causing the issue

Comment: The reason is because in the second `Else` you add any cell, which is without `ABC` or `DEF`. Thus, it is added to the `DelRng` and then the row is automatically deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I found that this highlighted the correct cells but then gave a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" instead of deleting anything. It did however work when I define the range as a single column ("C1:C100").

Comment: @MonteCristo Are you selecting columns `A:E` due to the varying column of "code"?

Comment: I've just updated it. Works fine in my test. It will also set the column dependent on where the cell containing "code" is located. Also look at the comments for a suggestion on how to avoid using 100 `Or`s